# IntelliJ Importing data to MySQL from CSV fails without apparent reason

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 and I'm trying to import file to a MySQL table from a CSV file. I have made sure that the "NOT NULL" fields are populated. But none of the rows seem to be imported.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the export error log - are there any records (there is 'Write error records to file' option in [import dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-table-dialog.html))? Please also try 2017.2.3 version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download it has this functionality improved a lot.

Comment: @Andrey yes I did. It only shows the rows that were not successfully imported. No reason given. Is there another log I can look at?

Comment: @Andrey Just downloaded `2017.2` and it worked! It was probably a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in IntelliJ `2016.2` version. I downloaded `2017.2` and it worked.